# Setup the BGP + ospf network

Tags: routing, bgp, ospf, gns3

I've the next Lab with GNS3

I have two autonomous systems(100,200), when the AS 100 run a OSPF with two areas, `0` and `1`. The AS 200 has only a router and computer, so easy. But I don't know how to setup the BGP protocol between the AS 100 and as 200.

**How should I setup R7 and R8 to work with BGP?**

[image: network overview]

The AS100

[image: network diagram, autonomous system 100]

The AS200

[image: network diagram, autonomous system 200]

### OSPF Setup

**R1:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 1.1.1.1
R1(config-router)#network 192.168.0.0  0.0.0.255 area 0
R1(config-router)#network 10.0.0.0  0.0.0.3 area 0
```

**R2:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 2.2.2.2
R1(config-router)#network 10.0.0.0  0.0.0.3 area 0
R1(config-router)#network 10.0.0.4  0.0.0.3 area 0
```

**R3:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 3.3.3.3
R1(config-router)#network 10.0.0.4  0.0.0.3 area 0
R1(config-router)#network 10.0.0.8  0.0.0.3 area 0
```

**R4:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 4.4.4.4
R1(config-router)#network 172.16.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 1
R1(config-router)#network 11.0.0.0  0.0.0.3 area 1
```

**R5:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 5.5.5.5
R1(config-router)#network 11.0.0.0  0.0.0.3 area 1
R1(config-router)#network 11.0.0.4  0.0.0.3 area 1
```

**R6:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 6.6.6.6
R1(config-router)#network 11.0.0.4  0.0.0.3 area 1
R1(config-router)#network 11.0.0.8  0.0.0.3 area 1
```

**R7:**

```
R1#enable
R1#configure terminal
R1(config)#router ospf 1
R1(config-router)#Router-id 7.7.7.7
R1(config-router)#network 10.0.0.8  0.0.0.3 area 0
R1(config-router)#network 11.0.0.8  0.0.0.3 area 1
```

### BGP Setup

**R7:**

```
R7#en
R7#conf t
R7(config)# router bgp 100
R7(config-router)#neighbor 190.0.0.2 remote-as 200
R7(config-router)#network 190.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.252
R7(config-router)#network 10.0.0.8 mask 255.255.255.252
R7(config-router)#network 11.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.252
```

**R8:**

```
R8#en
R8#conf t
R8(config)# router bgp 200
R8(config-router)#neighbor 190.0.0.1 remote-as 100
R8(config-router)#network 190.0.0.0 mask 255.255.255.252
R8(config-router)#network 173.31.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0
```

**R7 routing table:**

[image: R7 RIB]

**R8 routing table:**

[image: R8 RIB]

**Setup the vpcs**

```
VPCS[1]> ip 192.168.0.2 24 192.168.0.1
VPCS[1]> 2
VPCS[2]> ip 172.16.0.2 24 172.16.0.1
VPCS[2]> 3
VPCS[3]> ip 172.31.0.2 24 172.31.0.1
```

The problem is that when I try to do a ping from computer c3 to f0/0 or f0/01 in the router R7 not works only come until to s0/0.

**How should setup the router R7 and R8, to work with BGP?**

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/590623/setup-the-bgp-ospf-network. Please don't post the same question on multiple SE sites.

Comment: Does C3 have a default route to R8? Regards,

Comment: Would it be possible to enlarge or add more detail to your image?  As it stands now, the image is not very usable as it is difficult to read anything.  I had to zoom in over 200% to make any sense of the image myself.